# How to find the greatest number from a list before a specific index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list as follows:

```
[595.064,
 595.064,
 595.064,
 549.52,
 549.52,
 518.824,
 518.824,
 518.824,
 549.52,
 549.52,
 595.064,
 595.064]
```

Now, I am taking a user input like:

```
to_check = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

Based on what ever the number the user has inputted, I want to take that indexed number from the above given list and check **all the numbers before that position** and see if there exists any number greater than the obtained number or if the obtained number is the greatest.

Example:

If the user has given 5 as input:

```
to_check = int(input('Enter a number: ')) # user gives 5
obtained_value = values[to_check] # returns back 518.824
```

Now, I want to use this `obtained_value` and find the greatest number **before and including this number** in the list.

So, since the `obtained_value` is 518.824 and the index is 5, all the values between index 0 and index 5 have to be checked (`[595.064, 595.064, 595.064, 549.52, 549.52, 518.824]`). Since there exists a value which is greater than `obtained_value` (595.064), the value of `obtained_value` must be replaced with this greater number.

How do I do this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
max(your_list[0:to_check])
```

Comment: the replacement is missing

Comment: the replacement doesn't make much of a sense, imo

Comment: `to_check + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = max(values[0:to_check+1])
if m > values[to_check]:
    values[to_check] = m
```